# Is it Permissible to Consume Ezekiel Bread?

Tags: ezekiel--the-book

In Ezekiel 4:9, Ezekiel is told to prepare/create a repulsive bread - Ezekiel Bread - as an omen of the imminent hunger to come upon Israel due to siege (See Rashi). Assuming that today's recipes are similar (and clearly the manufacturer's intent is to recreate such bread - if today's recipes are wrong ... what if someone prepared it per the verse?), why is it permissible to eat it?

Ezekiel is told shortly thereafter to completely shave himself and destroy his hair in various ways - including casting a portion to the wind - once again a harbinger of imminent death and destruction. Per several editions, Rashi then adds (Ezekiel 5:3):

> From here is an allusion [to the fact] that whoever cuts his hair should not cast it away, but should hide it, **for any act written in these verses has implications of evil.**

If the acts written in these verses, generally, are portends of evil, and if we are, thus, not per Rashi to perform these acts *even today*, why consume the bread? Admittedly, this version of Rashi is not found in all editions, but several Achronim/later sages cite this Rashi in halachik treatises in the context of hair. The implication is that per these later sages this Rashi is to be relied upon.

Comment: "Assuming that today's recipes are similar" This doesn't seem like a very reasonable assumption.

Comment: Biblically accurate Ezekiel bread is baked with human excrement. It is that ingredient that provides the curse. Otherwise it was purely wholesome bread.

Comment: @ClintEastwood In the end, Ezekiel baked it with cow dung, not human excrement

Comment: FWIW there is an "Ezekiel Bread" with a hechsher see [here](https://www.foodforlife.com/product/breads/ezekiel-49-sprouted-whole-grain-bread)

Comment: @JoelK had he followed God's original instruction, the Jews would have repented and been saved.

Comment: God told Noah to build an ark before the flood... should we not build boats anymore?

Comment: The ark was an instrument of salvation so we should build boats. We should not flood the earth.

Comment: @ClintEastwood the bread was intended as an instrument of salvation as well... a prompt to teshubhah

Comment: so eat the bread, without the dung.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Y'chezkeil 4:12 and 4:15 indicate that dung was used to fuel the oven in which the bread was baked (which is also the general understanding of the commentators), not that dung was an ingredient in the bread (which, incidentally, would be a rabbinic violation of *bal t'shak'tzu* - [Rambam Hil. Ma'achalos Asuros 17:29](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=28&perek=17&halocha=29), or perhaps a biblical violation according to Sefer Chareidim (see 32:56)).

Comment: It still imparts flavor

Comment: @ClintEastwood It was (and still is in some places) a fairly common fuel source...

Comment: I'm machmir to eat bread fired in dung only when it exudes from a Shomer Shabbos Jew.